# Simulate ARMA process in matlab

Tags: matlab, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to simulate a time series process using Matlab. For example, let's see the following example: 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/arima.print.html

When I run following code

```
model = arima(1,0,1);
[fit,VarCov] = estimate(model,Y,'print',false);
```

I get the following error:

> ??? Undefined function or method 'arima' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Does  Matlab contain functions for Matlab? Can I calculate  different  functions,like  calculate autocorrelation or autocovariance  at different lag? Or estimate  ARMA  parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you have a license and code for the [Econometrics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/index.html) before using that function. MATLAB has annoying license requirements for both the main software and its various toolboxes :(

But, you may be able to find some public code that can do the same thing. Check out http://www.mathtools.net/

Comment: unfortunately  i have not it